# Kotlin picked image it doesn't show in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mobile, kotlin-android-extensions

Dialog fragment doesn't show photo that I selected from gallery

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode ==IMAGE_PICK_CODE){
        image_view.setImageURI(data?.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Select an image with a much lower resolution.

Comment: Can you give us more details. Have you tried to investigate logcat? What does it show? Also, are you using fileprovider?

Comment: @saiful103a The same code works when we try activity_main as a demo, but dialogfragment does not work either. I am not getting any errors either. I can select from gallery but cannot view the image. Also in DialogFragment

Comment: @blackapps I choose picture from emulator's gallery

Comment: Can be. But try a picture with lower resolution was the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert the image into a `Bitmap`, and and then use `.setImageBitmap()` to set the image to the `ImageView`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    val imageUri = data?.data
    val inputStream: InputStream? 
    try {
        inputStream = imageUri?.let { activity?.contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }
        // get a bitmap from a stream
        val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
        image_view.setImageBitmap(image)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        Log.d("TAG", "File not found: " + e.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unroselved reference contentResolver error

Comment: use activity?.contentResolver, because contentResolver comes from activity not from fragment.

Comment: @saiful103a  I use DialogFragment

Comment: @ezgiozkan have your tried `activity?.contentResolver` ?